# getting error while install any npm module

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js

I getting this error while install any module from npm and also not work with yarn.
I don't know where is the problem!

[image]

Comment: Are you behind any firewall?

Comment: @Jerodev no, my firewall is off

Comment: if your npm version is old, try upgrading

Comment: try this command ``npm config set strict-ssl false``

Answer (score 0):

Update NPM like :

```
npm update
```

Also i suggest you do with `-g`

```
"npm update -g" it will update globally installed packages.
```

Comment: @Grigor IWT  my npm is already upgrated to the latest version to the 6.1.1